# Finding the minimum shared value of two sorted sets over the network

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing

I have two nodes connected to each other over a network. They each have a *sorted* set of values (integers, in this case).

I want to find the minimum value of the intersection of the two sets. Due to latency and bandwidth constraints, it's not feasible to transfer one set to the other node and perform the operation locally.

Is there a way to find the minimum value of the intersection that does not require a O(N) data transfer, in as few steps as possible?

Edit:
These sets may be sparse. The minimum value of set A may not exist in set B.

Comment: Considering the minimum of two sets is minimum of minimums of individual sets - can each node find a minimum in its own set an have a single round trip with the other node to establish whose minimum is smaller?

Comment: Bugfix - operator typo ;(

Comment: @bobah: OP changed "union" to "intersection". :D

Comment: @EricDuminil yes, brain fail :D

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a Bloom Filter on one node, send it over to the other, which runs a bidirectional search, starting from the local minimum value.

This saves some data transfer, but requires a fair amount processing on both nodes.